# react redux dispatcher "Actions must be plain objects" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

when run this section return error "`Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`"

here is my code:

```
export function login(data) {
  const login_data = new FormData();

  login_data.append('username', data.username);
  login_data.append('password', data.password);
  login_data.append('grant_type', 'password');
  login_data.append('scope', 'read');

  return dispatch => {
    console.log("LOGIN DISPATCHER");
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + btoa('mobapp:SSSSS');
    return axios.post('http://172.16.79.25:9999/oauth/token', login_data)
    .then(res => {
      const token = res.data.access_token;
      localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
      setAuthorizationToken(token);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(token));
    });
  }
}
```

> console.log("LOGIN DISPATCHER") never run in this code!!

Comment: You are returning a promise on your dispatch

Comment: Have you added `thunk` middleware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action actually return a function, not a plain object that "plain" redux needs.

You need to add some middleware to handle this kind of action like `redux-thunk`.

Here is the sample setup:

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

Comment: just add `import thunk from 'redux-thunk'` ?

Comment: Updated in answer.